# Problema ao acessar Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

**ApiController**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ClienteController : Controller
{
    private IClienteRepository _ClienteRepository;

    public ClienteController(IClienteRepository clienteRepository)
    {
        _ClienteRepository = clienteRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Cliente> Get()
    {
        return _ClienteRepository.Get(x => x.ClienteId > 0);
    }
}
```

**Stratup**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IClienteRepository, ClienteRepository>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

**LaunchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52676/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/cliente",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Safra.AberturaDeContas.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/cliente",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52677/"
    }
  }
}
```

Erro ao subir a api acessando o http://localhost:52676/api/cliente:

> This localhost page can’t be found

Comment: Pelo que parece seu controller não tem nenhum método Get, tem apenas um Post, e via navegador, você faz um GET.

Comment: Usando o Postman com o método Post também não estou tendo o retorno

Comment: o código de status está sendo 200 ?

Comment: usando a URL = http://localhost:52676/Cliente/ObterClientes e http://localhost:52676/api/Cliente/ObterClientes , Retorno = 404 Not Found

Comment: Consegui @Lucas Brogni, usei a URL: http://localhost:52676/Cliente/ObterClientes e Decorei meu método `[HttpPost]
        [Route("/Cliente/ObterClientes")]
        public IEnumerable<Cliente> ObterClientes()
        {
            return _ClienteRepository.Get(x => x.ClienteId > 0);
        }`